# Is there any way to get AMDGPU-PRO drivers working on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, video, amd-graphics

I have an R9 380, which is supported by the driver. I followed all of AMD's instructions perfectly and everything seemed fine until I restarted. After restarting there was no video but there was sound. The only solution to this problem seems to be uninstalling the driver :/. Is there anyway to get the driver working? Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the "Additional Drivers" app. (Search for `addi` on your Dash and it should dhow up).

[Additional Drivers App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPpA4.png)

This will show any extra drivers that are available for your hardware.
As you can see, I'm currently using the drivers that NVIDIA provides for my graphics card.
The drivers for your card should show up there too.

To install them, just select them and click apply changes.

Good luck!